# No access to path key on file upload

Tags: javascript, html, image, reactjs

I am trying to get access to `HTMLElementInput.files.path` to send to my backend for `cloudinary` to process. The problem I am running into is there is now `path` key present on the object.

[image]

I've been reading through the [MDN Input page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file), and I'm pretty sure I'm not doing anything wrong with the markup. The below is the code I have for intercepting the data on the `input`:

```
class App extends Component {
  capture(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const image = document.querySelector('input').files[0];
    console.log(image);
    // image.path === undefined
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <form onSubmit={e => this.capture(e)}>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="photo_image">Upload an image</label>
            <input id="photo_image" type="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" />
          </div>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
   }
}

export default App;
```

I am stumped. If someone sees where I'm going wrong or if there is a *gotcha* with `react` that I don't know about I am all ears!

## Update

I should have left this information before, my apologies. The project is bootstrapped with `create-react-app`. I get this problem in development as well as when serving the build in production.

- `create-react-app@1.3.3`
- `react-scripts@1.0.10`
- `node@8.2.1`
- `yarn@0.27.5`
- `macOS@10.12.6`
- `chrome@59.0.3071.115`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was still in an `electron` mindset and did not ever think that MDN was telling me the truth that the *browser* does not give me access to the hard path of a file on the system for security reasons. This code box that was sent to me in Reactiflux shows a method for obtaining the end goal I was looking for, many thanks to @BTM for this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/lNN5pK6M

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the brackets around event while catching the event onSubmit. Change it to below code and try:

```
<form onSubmit= {(e) => this.capture(e)}>
```

Comment: with ES6 you don't need brackets when passing single arguments

Comment: Thanks for updating my knowledge on this.